# Error trying to run android app onto emulator with phonegap, how can I fix it?

Tags: android, ubuntu, cordova, android-emulator

I have phonegap 3.0.0-0.14.3 installed on Ubuntu 12.04.

I want to run the app with android emulator. When I run `phonegap run android` I get the following:

```
[phonegap] compiling Android...
[phonegap] successfully compiled Android app
[phonegap] trying to install app onto device
[phonegap] no device was found
[phonegap] trying to install app onto emulator
   [error] An error occurred while emulating/deploying the android project.Warning : [ --debug | --release | --nobuild ] not specified, defaulting to --debug
Cleaning project...
```

The app run onto a device without problem.

Please help!

Comment: The emulator is running?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Finally I found an answer to my question.

I was getting this error because I had not created an android virtual device. After having created one, everything worked normally.

On command prompt just type : `android avd` to display de AVD Manager window, then you can create an android virtual device.

I hope this is helpful to someone.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! This solved my issue before it happend!

Answer (score 0):

In the new version the adb is moved to new folder on my environment its
D:\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools. So you need to inlcude this new location in the path.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Cordova over MacOSX. 
You should try something like:

```
sudo android create avd --name myCordova --target 1 --abi default/armeabi-v7a --force
```

instead of:

```
android create avd --name myCordova --target 1 --abi default/armeabi-v7a --force
```

It works for me