# I am trying to run an android app in adt using phonegap

Tags: android, cordova

I have seen some example in SO but these solution doesn't work on my error. My error is below:-

```
[phonegap] compiling Android...
[phonegap] successfully compiled Android app
[phonegap] trying to install app onto device
[phonegap] no device was found
[phonegap] trying to install app onto emulator
   [error] An error occurred while emulating/deploying the android project.
    event.js:72
        throw er;// Unhandled error exception
```

I have seen the below example but it is not working [Error trying to run android app onto emulator with phonegap, how can I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19296779/error-trying-to-run-android-app-onto-emulator-with-phonegap-how-can-i-fix-it)

Comment: Can you run with `-d` to see if it outputs more information please?

Comment: I have followed http://devgirl.org/2013/07/17/tutorial-implement-push-notifications-in-your-phonegap-application/ tutorial to send push notification.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have got the solution. My emulator was not started that's why it was showing error. I have started emulator the tried now it is working. Thanks everyone who tried to help me.

Comment: Thanks! Works like you say!

Answer (score 2):

I have just tried it and get positive results. There is an error but to get rid of it:

1. Write on CLI android you will see android SDK manager .
2. Open android 4.2.2 and check SDK platform and ARM EABI v7a System Image
3. Click on install package
4. Now you run your command of phonegap i-e phonegap install android

Answer (score 0):

You can check [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20421688/how-to-send-push-notification-using-phonegap-and-parse) and [this tutorial](http://devgirl.org/2013/07/17/tutorial-implement-push-notifications-in-your-phonegap-application/). I think this will help you.

Comment: this answer has nothing to do with the problem asked!

Comment: @BikashChandraMondal Yes it worked, please update the answer also according to the comment